# Address Book UI Framework deprecated methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbookui

I am working on an existing objective c project , While reading Address Book UI Framework Reference for iOS i found the below classes have deprecated in iOS 9 .
( `ABUnknownPersonViewController` , `ABPersonViewController` , `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, `ABNewPersonViewController` )
What is the replacement of this .? Where i can find some document related this . any help appreciated . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `AddressBookUI` framework has been deprecated in `iOS 9`, so better you should use `ContactsUI` Framework.

It has many new features including all the features of `AddressBookUI` framework.

So, in case if you are targeting the `iOS 9` specifically then you should go for `ContactsUI` Framework.

To check that `AddressBookUI` framework is available for specific `iOS` version you can do the following:

```
if ([CNContactStore class]) {
  CNContactStore *store = [CNContactStore new];
  //...
} else {
  // Fallback to old framework
}
```

Here is the complete code for that:

```
- (void) contactScan
{
    if ([CNContactStore class]) {
        //ios9 or later
        CNEntityType entityType = CNEntityTypeContacts;
        if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
         {
             CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
             [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:entityType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if(granted){
                     [self getAllContact];
                 }
             }];
         }
        else if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:entityType]== CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        {
            [self getAllContact];
        }
    }
}

-(void)getAllContact
{
    if([CNContactStore class])
    {
        //iOS 9 or later
        NSError* contactError;
        CNContactStore* addressBook = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];
        [addressBook containersMatchingPredicate:[CNContainer predicateForContainersWithIdentifiers: @[addressBook.defaultContainerIdentifier]] error:&contactError];
        NSArray * keysToFetch =@[CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey];
        CNContactFetchRequest * request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc]initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];
        BOOL success = [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&contactError usingBlock:^(CNContact * __nonnull contact, BOOL * __nonnull stop){
            [self parseContactWithContact:contact];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)parseContactWithContact :(CNContact* )contact
{
    NSString * firstName =  contact.givenName;
    NSString * lastName =  contact.familyName;
    NSString * phone = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];
    NSStrubg * email = [contact.emailAddresses valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSArray * addrArr = [self parseAddressWithContac:contact];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)parseAddressWithContac: (CNContact *)contact
{
    NSMutableArray * addrArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    CNPostalAddressFormatter * formatter = [[CNPostalAddressFormatter alloc]init];
    NSArray * addresses = (NSArray*)[contact.postalAddresses valueForKey:@"value"];
    if (addresses.count > 0) {
        for (CNPostalAddress* address in addresses) {
            [addrArr addObject:[formatter stringFromPostalAddress:address]];
        }
    }
    return addrArr;
}
```

Just make sure that you ask the permission to read the contacts from device.

Reference link: https://gist.github.com/willthink/024f1394474e70904728

> Updated:

For replacement for `AddressBookUI` you need to use `CNContactPickerViewController`. You can check the delegate methods which can be used to pickup the one or multiple contacts at a time.

This will present a inbuilt `UIViewController` with all the contacts and you need to implement the delegate methods of it!

> To select one contact:

```
contactPicker:didSelectContact:
```

> To select multiple (New Feature):

```
contactPicker:didSelectContacts:
```

`CNContactPickerDelegate` reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: I am assuming ContactsUI won't be available for <9.0 iOS versions? Let's suppose I am targeting iOS 7 and above. How do you suppose I should tackle it? (Since I am getting deprecated warning for methods using AddressBook Framework\

Comment: Yes, you should tackle that method using the above code `if ([CNContactStore class]) {
  CNContactStore *store = [CNContactStore new];
  //...
} else {
  // Fallback to old framework
}`

Comment: But falling back to old method will still retain the deprecated warning in my project. What's the incentive of moving to ContactsUI then?

Comment: The advantage is `AddressBookUI` is unavailable in `iOS 9`, so there you must be use `ContactsUI` and if you running on earlier version then you must be using `AddressBookUI` there `ContactsUI` will not be available. 

P.S. The deprecated warning will be there!

Comment: Not really. Even though it is deprecated, `AddressBookUI` is still working for iOS 9 in my App. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Yes it will be! But as the method are deprecated the Apple can stop support for it! So, the only option is to use the `ContactsUI`

Comment: I believe that if you specify a deployment target of less than iOS 9.0, Xcode will stop warning you about the deprecation? Happens for other deprecated methods/classes etc.

Comment: @Rob I have updated the answer. Thanks for spotting me out!

Comment: How about the view for creating a new contact?
Should I use this?
``init(forUnknownContact contact: CNContact)``
and then the user can add the contact?
The problem it's I have 2 steps before creating a contact.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has introduced new framework for this for iOS9 and above please fine below link  [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html)

Edit:
one more link :[Link2](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-contacts-framework/)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. At the very least you should mention the name of the new framework (in this case, `ContactsUI`) so that if the links break in the future, someone reading the answer can at least search it by name.